# Run a long running task in Kotlin (Ktor backend)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

In my Ktor backend, I have a simple get API request. It will make some database update and finally return a message. But, before returning the response, the API will initiate a long-running task (some database operation and file writing tasks) which might take some time to finish. The long-running task should continue its job even if the API returns its response.

This is my get API request

```
routing {
    get("/testAPI") {

        val x= queryResolver()
        println(" return from API")
        call.respondText("Hello ..")
    }
}
```

Below are my handling functions.  `queryResolver()` is called from the API and then it will call `myService()` which will call `db_update1()`, `db_update2()` and finally starts the `long_running_task()` .

```
suspend fun queryResolver(): String{
    println(" queryResolver- start -${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(2000)
    val x = myService()
    println(" queryResolver - end")
    return "..return from queryResolver  "
}

suspend fun myService(): String{
    println(" service - start -${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(2000)
    val x = db_update1()
    val y = db_update2()
    
    GlobalScope.launch() {
        println(".. launch start -${Thread.currentThread().name} ")
        long_running_task()
        println(".. launch - end ")
    }
    
    println(" service - end")
    return "..return from service -> "
}


suspend fun db_update1(): String{
    println(" db_update1 - start -${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(2000)
    println(" db_update1 - end")
    return "..return from db_update1 -> "
}

suspend fun db_update2(): String{
    println(" db_update2 - start -${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(3000)
    println(" db_update2 - end")
    return "..return from db_update2 -> "
}

suspend fun long_running_task(): String{
    println("### long_running_task - start -${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(10000)
    println("### long_running_task - end")
    return "..return from long_running_task -> "
}
```

This code gives the below output which is desired output.

```
 Start API
 queryResolver- start -eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2
 service - start -eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2
 db_update1 - start -eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2
 db_update1 - end
 db_update2 - start -eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2
 db_update2 - end
 service - end
 queryResolver - end
 return from API
.. launch start -DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
### long_running_task - start -DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
### long_running_task - end
.. launch - end
```

But, using the global scope is not a good idea in this case.
Now, what is the best way to keep alive(to allow it to finish its task) the long_running_task() even if the API response returns?
If I want to reuse the scope and the context of the existing scope and context how can I do that?

Comment: What is the lifetime of this long-running task? Should it keep running forever if something hangs inside? How do you intend to cancel such tasks? This is what determines the coroutine scope to use to launch it. `GlobalScope` is ok sometimes, when the coroutine you're launching is actually meant to run "forever". But in cases like this, there is likely a moment when you want to cancel the task, or all the tasks that could have been launched by this function. If there isn't, then maybe you can define your own top-level scope, maybe with exception handler and logging (and supervisor job).

Comment: long-running task should not run forever. It will be running for some time @Joffrey